# Where can I find the Sync Key in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-sync

I want to add other computers to a sync account with Firefox 12 (Windows)

In the [Firefox support pages](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-manage-my-firefox-sync-account#w_where-can-i-find-my-sync-key), procedures are given for accessing the "Sync Key" and 
the "Recovery Key":

> At the top of the Firefox window, click on the Tools menu and select Options.
>   Select the Sync panel.
>   Click Manage Account and then select My Sync Key. Find Sync Key

In Firefox 12 under Windows, The "Manage Account" menu on the Sync options dialog has only these choices:

- View Quota
- Change Password
- My Recovery Key
- Reset Sync

[image]

Where has the "Sync Key" moved to? Or how is the Sync Key accessed?

Comment: Firefox support pages try to detect the Firefox version you use to visit. So if you still see the term "Sync key" while using Firefox 12, your User-Agent string might have been modified, so your version is misdetected. Open `about:config`, filter for `general.useragent` and reset any bold entry via the context menu.

Comment: I have not changed anything. This is a new FF12 upgrade. Here is my setting: general.useragent.compatMode.firefox;false.  If you go to the Support link above, you do see any mentions of "Sync Key"?

Comment: There should be more than one entry beginning with `general.useragent`. If none of them are bold for you, you maybe are using an extension like User Agent Switcher, that changes the string by itself. The page indeed mentions "Sync Key" in Firefox 3.6 and "Recovery Key" with Firefox 12 here. Disabling JavaScript shows both wordings in both versions. Naming changed beginning with version 9.

Comment: Ooops - NoScript was blocking the jscript. I'm impressed how the mozilla site has dynamic content on the same page, based on browser version.  With jscript enabled, the descriptions of sync key disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Sync Key** was been replaced with the **Recovery Key**. Clicking on `Pair a Device` and then `I don't have the device with me` will also give you the Recovery Key.

[image: options]

[image: no device]

[image: recovery key]